# Plot an unknown netcdf file (without ncview)

Tags: python, plot, netcdf

I am starting with the netcdf in python and I want to know more options to view the netcdf in a friendly way

In raster cases (2D or 3D) I can use ncview, but there are cases that only give me longitude, latitude, and others variables (as height for example) or save polygons contours or lines, I would like to visualize this a friendly way (as in QGis format) in order to have a better data overview

```
import netCDF4
src = netCDF4.Dataset(file)
var_names = src.variables.keys()

float32 nav_lat(y, x)
    units: degrees_north
    long_name: Latitude
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (10800, 21600)

float32 upst(y, x)
    axis: TYX
    units: m2
    long_name: area
    associate: nav_lat nav_lon
    coordinates: nav_lat nav_lon
unlimited dimensions: 
current shape = (10800, 21600)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it with ncplot (https://pypi.org/project/ncplot/) which provides ncview style auto-plotting in Python.:

```
from ncplot import view

view(file)
```

Though if ncview cannot automatically plot it, there may be some data issues.ncview should be able to handle almost anything.